# Make youtube video play fullscreen in website, with no controls

Tags: html, html5-video

I want a youtube video to play full-screen on a website, with no controls, no knowledge that it is YouTube. Like what is done over at [gaben.tv](http://gaben.tv/). Prefrebly all in html, Is this possible? Well I know it's possible, because it was done, but how do i do it? Or achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at their source code (right-click > view Source, or better yet use e.g. [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index)) you see that they used [jQuery.mb.YTPlayer](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-ytplayer/).

Comment: I had a look at the source, but I didn't even realise that was a thing. Thank you so much.